# How to go back and forth in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

So I have a problem to solve for one of my classes. 10 people cout to 100 and the conditions are if the number is divisible by 7 they switch directions, means the 6th person will say 6, 7th will say 7 and 6th will say 8. If the number is divisible by 11 they jump one person. So if the 12th is next they go to the 13th person. I was able to write and understand the problem but I cannot find a way to iterate through the array index so I can satisfy what the problem inquires. Below is my code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String persoane[] = {"Marcus  ", "Fane", "Ion ", "Ghita ", "Fanescu ", "Vrabie ", "Ecaterina ", "Marius ", "Florina ", "Lupu "};

        int numaratoare = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
            numaratoare = i;
            if (numaratoare%7==0) {

            }

            if (numaratoare%11==0){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are 10 people, you don't have a 12th or 13th person. Also, you haven't actually explained what the program should do; should it print something?

Comment: So just to confirm - if number is divisible by 11, you 'jump' one person - i.e. go from person 1, to person 2. If the number is divisible by 7, you go back one person, i.e. go from person 5 to person 4, who continues counting. Are those the only rules for changing the currently counting person?

Comment: 10 friends are sitting in a circle around a table and decide to play a new game. In it, they count up through the numbers from 1 to 100. The first person says "1", the second says "2" and so on... but with a few catches:

Whenever the number is divisible by 7, they switch directions. So person 6 will say "6", person 7 will say "7", then person 6 again will say "8".
Whenever the number is divisible by 11, they skip the next person.

Comment: The way I read "switch direction", it should continue counting down until you get to another multiple of 7.

Comment: To make sure we're on the same page, I suggest you add an example to your question: "P1: 1, P2: 2, P3: 3, P4: 4, P5: 5, P6: 6, P7: 7, P6: 8, P5: 9, P4: 10, P3: 11, P1: 12, P10: 13, P9: 14, P10: 15, P1: 16 ..."

Comment: It  is counting from 1 to 100. I understand the whole problem, I just do not know how to add or substract from the array index inside the if statements and I can't seem to find anything on internet about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need two counters for this problem, one for the 100 numbers and the other one for the people. Also, you need to know which one is the direction for the people's counter. 
The solution could be something like this:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String persoane[] = {"Marcus", "Fane", "Ion", "Ghita", "Fanescu", "Vrabie", "Ecaterina", "Marius",
        "Florina", "Lupu"};

        int personCounter = 0;
        boolean directionInverse = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            if (i % 7 == 0) {
                personCounter--;
                directionInverse = true;
            }

            if (i % 11 == 0){
                personCounter++;
                directionInverse = false;
            }

            if (directionInverse) {
                personCounter--;
                if (personCounter == -1) {
                    personCounter = 9;
                }
            } else {
                personCounter++;
            }
            System.out.println(persoane[personCounter % 10] + " says " + (i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- I have created a direction flag for traversing the array.

2 - an index to traverse the array.

3 - An answer variable to find out that on which position, you are in when count reach to 100.

4 - debug the code properly and try carefully to understand each statement.

5 - comment if you have any issue with code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String persoane[] = { "Marcus  ", "Fane", "Ion ", "Ghita ", "Fanescu ", "Vrabie ", "Ecaterina ", "Marius ",
            "Florina ", "Lupu " };

    int numaratoare = 0;
    boolean direction = true;
    int answer = 0;
    int index = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

        if (index == 0 && direction == false) {
            index = persoane.length - 1;
        }
        if (index == persoane.length - 1 && direction) {
            index = 0;
        }
        numaratoare = i;

        if (numaratoare % 7 == 0) {

            if (direction) {
                direction = false;
            } else {
                direction = true;
            }
        }

        if (numaratoare % 11 == 0) {

            if (direction) {
                if( index == 9) {
                    index = 0;
                }else{
                    index++;    
                }

            } else {
                if( index == 0) {
                    index = 9;
                }else{
                    index--;    
                }
            }
        }
        if (i == 99) {
            answer = index;
        }
        if (direction) {
            index++;
        } else {
            index--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if question is old, it is just an interesting problem:

```
 public static void count(){
        String persoane[] = {"Marcus", "Fane", "Ion", "Ghita", "Fanescu", "Vrabie", "Ecaterina", "Marius", "Florina", "Lupu"};

        int index = 0;
        boolean direction = true;

        for (int i=1; i<100; i++){
            if (i%7==0) {
                direction = !direction;
            }

            if (i%11==0){
                if(direction){
                    index = (index+2)%9;
                } else {
                    index = (9 + (index-2))%9;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if(direction){
                index = (index+1)%9;
            } else {
                index = (9 + (index-1))%9;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Last person " + persoane[index]);
    }
```